# How to pack dotnet core from source code?

Tags: .net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, open-source

My environment: Ubuntu 18.04-x64

I want to build .NET Core 2.2.2 from source code and get the [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/build/distribution-packaging) as if I download .NET Core SDK.

I used for this purpose [source-build](https://github.com/dotnet/source-build) repo, installed prerequirements, ran build.sh and it successfully finished. As result, I get some new folders: bin, packages, tools.

I'm not sure at all where to found needed files and I went to **bin** folder I found only **.nupkg** and **.tar.gz** archives. I unpacked **dotnet-sdk-2.2.104-linux-x64.tar.gz**, and found files structure like needed structure (see above). But in folder **shared** I found **only**

> Microsoft.NETCore.App

And when I want to run my MVC prject dotnet threw:

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.2'
>   was not found.

In other side I [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/build/):

> normally you're only interested in the NuGet packages, which are
>   placed in the .nuget\pkg subdirectory of the previous output
>   directory.

So I’m really confused where to look result set of files.

**My questions:**

1. Where are placed set of files which named ".NET Core SDK"
2. Need I build something else to get Microsoft.AspNetCore.App with
       it's liblrary files
3. In **source-build** repo in **init-tools.sh** I found

> echo "Installing dotnet cli..."
>       __DOTNET_LOCATION="https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/${__DOTNET_TOOLS_VERSION}/${__DOTNET_PKG}.tar.gz"

What's the point to download SDK, if it should be build

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the runtime to the AspNetCore, I'm sure that you have the runtime to the .NETCORE, but the Asp is a separate runtime and you need to install, I share the URL https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

But I recommended updating your project to the lasted version 3.1

Answer (score -2):

The SDK is for developing applications *on* .NET Core. You do not need to build .NET Core itself unless you are actually developing .NET Core itself, i.e. you want to contribute to the .NET Core open-source project. If you just want to build .NET Core applications, install the SDK.